# How to install the newest version of GDAL in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, gdal, windows

I have Python 3.9 installed in AppData and I have a project with a virtual environment (venv). Furthermore I have downloaded `gdal-305-1930-x64-core.msi` and installed it in the Programs folder. Additionally I have set C:\Program Files\GDAL to the `PATH` environment variable, the `GDAL_DATA` variable to C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data and `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` to C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins.

Morover, I also installed the MS Build Tools 17.3.2.

Then I downloaded `GDAL-3.5.1.win-amd64-py3.9.msi` and installed it inside the venv folder of my python project.

However, I got this error message when I want to execute the code:

```
On Windows, with Python >= 3.8, DLLs are no longer imported from the PATH.
If gdalXXX.dll is in the PATH, then set the USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES environment variable
to feed the PATH into os.add_dll_directory().
```

If I set this variable in code:

```
os.environ["USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON"] = "YES"
```

I will get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'
```

I do not want to use wheels from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) because they are not the newest ones and I want to test a new driver. Using conda is also not an option.

Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: Have you tried OSGeo4W installer https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/? It can install everything needed for running GDAL with Python, including Python.

Comment: what happens when you type 'import osgeo' from the python terminal?

Comment: @Kartograaf If I "import osgeo" in the shell (the app data python is executed I think, not the venv) then "No module named osgeo" is printed.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for this advice. I got gdal 3.5.1 running (in console) but not 3.6.0 (nightly build). What do I have to download and in which folder the nightly builds are installed (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe)? Some dlls are missing.

Comment: @user30184 neverminde gdal 3.6.0. gdal 3.5.1 has the driver I was looking for. I only need to get gdal to python now